# IE reading inherited font size from computed style (currentStyle) is incorrect

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I've put a little test case together here:

http://jsfiddle.net/D4sLk/2/

Basically I have the following font sizes set:

- * (everything): `12px`
- container: `20px`
- test element: `inherit`

The DOM hierarchy is: *container* > *test element*.

In IE9, the font size is reported as 12px using `testEl.currentStyle.fontSize` but is displayed as 20px. In Chrome and FF it seems fine.

Are there any workarounds to this issue? Or have I done something really stupid?

Comment: It would be interesting as an experiment to see if jQuery (via `.css()`) reported the right (or wrong) size.

Comment: was just trying that...

Comment: Huh! No jQuery result is also wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/D4sLk/3/

Comment: Always post the relevant code and markup **in the question itself**, don't just link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `font-size: 1em` instead of using `inherit`.

The reason for this is because I've found that `inherit` seems to have issues in IE. It rendered fine when I looked in IE9, however for some reason `testEl.currentStyle.fontSize` and `$(testEl).css('font-size')` both returned 12px as well.

I've read that to use font-size: inherit in IE8, you would need to specify a !DOCTYPE, however it should be fine in IE9 (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp). For some reason, `testEl.currentStyle.fontSize` and `$(testEl).css('font-size')` are not picking up the correct values in IE9.

When you set the font-size to 1em, you are sizing it up to 100% of the parent font-size, which in this case results to 20px. From http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp:

> 1em is equal to the current font size. 2em means 2 times the size of the current font. E.g., if an element is displayed with a font of 12 pt, then '2em' is 24 pt. The 'em' is a very useful unit in CSS, since it can adapt automatically to the font that the reader uses

As a result, `computedStyle.fontSize` and `$(testEl).css('font-size')`, should both return 20px.

Hope this helps!